# Real Time Data in ASP.net Web Form App : How to update (refresh) screen with new incoming data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know many questions have been posted on this particular topic but I couldn't find any that fit my situation.

**My test app is built with ASP.Net Web Forms. The library I use is a .Net library not compatible with .Net Core so I'm limited to .net Framework.**

I'm retrieving data from a PLC Server(Modbus protocol using TCP/IP) using a third party library that supplies connection and data handling classes, handlers... I didn't need to implement "Models" or "Controllers" since everything is handled within classes. Here is an example :

```cs
//References
 using AutomatedSolutions.Win.Comm;
 using MB = AutomatedSolutions.Win.Comm.MB.Master;
 using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Properties Instantiation
  mbChannel = new MB.Net.Channel(); //Connection to the server TCP/IP
  device1 = new MB.Device(); //Device sending data (temp, speed, ...)
  group1 = new MB.Group(false, 500); //Abstract class with a "dataChanged event"

  item1 = new MB.Item(); //Represents a specific data point (tag)

  group1.Items.Add(item1);
  mbChannel.Devices.Add(device1);
  device1.Groups.Add(group1);

 //Data changed Event Handler
  item1.DataChanged += new Item.DataChangedEventHandler(Item_DataChanged);

 //Polling activation
  group1.Active = true;
}
```

Once connected to the server, the "Item.DataChangedEventHandler" is triggered every 500 ms and new data can be retrieved from the "item".

**"Item.DataChangedEventHandler"** code :

```cs
private void Item_DataChanged(object sender, EventArgs evArgs)
        {
            Item evItem = (Item)sender;
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " Item.DataChange event fired, quality is " + evItem.Quality.ToString();
            if (evItem.Quality == AutomatedSolutions.Win.Comm.Quality.GOOD)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < evItem.Elements; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(evItem.Values[i].ToString() + ",");
                }
                WriteResult(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**WriteResults** code :

```cs
        private void WriteResult(string result)
        {
            Result.Text = result;
        }
```

**DoRead** code : **This function is triggered by a button action and reads one item at a time. This works fine and read values are shown in the "TextBox"**

```cs
        private void DoRead(TextBox tb)
        {
            Result result;
            try
            {
                device1.Read(item1, out result);
                if (result.IsOK)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < item1.Elements; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(item1.Values[i].ToString() + ",");
                        sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;
                        tb.Text = sb.ToString();
                        TextBox1.Text = "Success";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + result.EvArgs.Message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

**My issue is that while reading the item's values with "DoRead" method works fine, data collected from the "dataChanged" event are not shown.** TextChanged Event is not triggered.

How can I update the page with the incoming  data?

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the nature of web forms. Once the response gets to the client, nothing on the server side is happening until something like a postback is triggered from the client. Because the "Item_DataChanged" event is triggered from a server side object, the web page on the client side can't see it after load.

Comment: Ah! OK... Yeah, that's why using a time to refresh the page didn't do anything... Also tried "AutoPostback" on the TextBox but didn't work either. Nothing is triggered... Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as noted, you need to grasp the life cycle of a web form or page.

That code behind ONLY exists DURING what we call a round trip.

So, the user requests a web page. the page class and variables etc. are created. The code behind runs, and the page is sent to the client side.

THEN the server side page is tossed out - does NOT exist anymore
(now read this over and over!! - the server side code, varibles and page is TOSSED OUT - it does NOT exist!!!).

you MUST without ANY doubt grasp the above concpet.

So, the web page is now sent to the client side, browser replots that page. it is just sitting on the users desktop and the server page code/page/variable etc. is NOW GONE!!!!

The end user can pull the plug on their computer, maybe hit a short cut and go to google.com. The page is disconnected from the web server!

It never WAS connected. The web page just sits on the users desktop. the code behind is LONG GONE - does NOT exist anymore!!!

The web server is thus just sitting there. It is waiting for a post-back from ANY user. It does not hold or keep a copy of YOUR web page and code in memory. The web server can take ANY web page request.

So, you can NOT have and KEEP some code in a web page running during this process.

If any of the 10 users with a web page sitting on their desktop clicks a button? Then if a post-back occurs, then that WHOLE web page is sent to the ONE web server waiting for that request.

The page is then re-loaded. The page class and variables are re-initialized (starts from scratch). The code behind now runs. You can change things on the web page, and ONLY WHEN ALL code is done running is THEN the page sent back to the browser, and the browser then re-loads that WHOLE page again.

I mean, what happens if 10 users post that page? You now have 10 copies of that code and page running!!!! Which one is going to be connected to that exterinal process??

You have this setup:

[image]

Note how the page is sitting CLIENT side. On the server, THERE IS NOT a instance of that page class. (read this sentence again!!!)

NOTE VERY careful here - the web page is ON CLIENT computer - it is NOT existing at all on the web server side.

You do not have this:

[image]

And you DO NOT HAVE this either:

[image]

In above it shows the web page on the user desktop, and then the web page on the server.

you do NOT have that setup.

The page SERVER SIDE DOES NOT exist.

So, you have a web page,and you click a button:

Ok, You click the button. Now the so called round trip starts.

[image]

So you click a button the WHOLE WEB page is THEN
sent up to the server. You now have this:

[image]

Now in above, the diagram I suppose COULD show that the web page is ALSO still client side. But I left it out.

NOW a instance of the page class is created, and your code behind starts running.

Your code behind can modify controls (even visible), but the page is NOT interacting with the user - ONLY code can MODIFY the web page.

web page is THEN sent back to the client side, and the server side class instance and code is TOSSED OUT - DOES NOT exist!!!

You now have this:
[image]

So the code behind NEVER really directly interacts with the user.

you code can ONLY modify the web page DURING that short trip up to the server. Code behind runs - modify web page, and THEN the WHOLE page is sent back to client side.

So you never interact directly with the user, but ONLY interact with the web page, ad ONLY for a VERY short time.

What this suggests?

It quite much means you probably should run a 100% seperate process outside of the web site that interacts with that one other source. It could update a table, and then say your web site could have a timer re-fresh that re-loads say ever 1 or 2 seconds.

And I doubt that machine would be happy if 10 users launched a web page, and now all 10 of them start hitting that external system. However, what is worse?

Well, the code might connect to that box, setup some code to receive some info every so often, but as noted, as soon as the code behind is done, then the whole web page is now sent back down to client side and the server side code + page is TOSSED out, and does NOT exist anymore.

Only when you post back again then the code ad page starts over from scratch (no previous code values or variables exist from last post-back).

Now, having stated the above?

You could have  form with a timer that fires say ever 1 or 2 seconds. And if  you really need a "real time" connection from the web page to the server, then you would look into using what is called asp.net signalR. Its a bit of work to setup, so the timer idea probably is easer to start out with.

But, asp.net signalR probably the best choice.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#:~:text=What%20is%20SignalR%3F%20ASP.NET%20SignalR%20is%20a%20library,process%20of%20adding%20real-time%20web%20functionality%20to%20applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#:%7E:text=What%20is%20SignalR%3F%20ASP.NET%20SignalR%20is%20a%20library,process%20of%20adding%20real-time%20web%20functionality%20to%20applications).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried a timer but the page was still not being updated. There might be something else wrong... I'll look into Signal R and see if I'm able to set it up. Thanks again!

Comment: But a timer still means the above page life cycle. The timer fires - page goes to server. The code, the variables, what you have in that web form is NOW created from scratch. Once the code runs once, then the page travels back to client side. (server side page is now gone). So, you should have realized this can't work by looking at the pretty pictures I provided. You can't have code behind halt, or wait, since then the web page is stuck on server side. ONLY when the code is done, does the page travel back down to client side. This is called state-less programming.

Comment: If it was/is ok to re-connect, and pull data  each time from the "thing" on each timer event, then fine. But you can't say use DataChangedEventHandler, since the code in the web page is GONE!! when page travels back to client. You could as noted, perhaps start a separate code thread / process, and then update session(), or even a database table. So, you could/would run that code + process separate from the web site, and thus on each page refresh you query table or session() get that data. But the fact that you attempted a timer shows you did not grasp those pretty pictures.

Comment: In fact I tried the timer before posting this question but yes I need to understand that process before doing anything else. Thanks for the ideas, I'll look into them!